# how to change Label content(In XAML file) to Lower to upper and Upper to case in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ShiftAltClickValue2Animate">

        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="lbl_AWithDiaeresis">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Ä"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="ä"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I created one Storyboard in wpf.Then apply the same stoaryboard to many controls in **code behind**.So i have to change lablel content **upper to lower case and lower to upper case** in Freame by Frame.

With above code is possible for one control and not possible in many control. what should i do for that.